# How to remove author names on page 1 in elsarticle?

Tags: titles, elsarticle

We are writing a paper to submit to an Elsevier Journal. It requires that the author names appear only on the title/abstract page but not on the first page of the paper (in order to support the double-blind review process).

How do we keep author names on abstract page but remove the author names on the first page?

Here is a snippet:

```
\documentclass[times,preprint,10pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{A Framework for Analytics and Simulation}
\author[]{R ~K\fnref{fn1}}
 \ead{rk@gcos.com}

 \author[]{Jack ~G\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn2}}
 \ead{Jack@gcos.com}

 \author[]{P ~E\fnref{fn3}}
 \ead{pe@gcos.com}

\cortext[cor1]{Principal corresponding author}
\fntext[fn1]{LSU}
\fntext[fn2]{CEAS }
 \fntext[fn3]{CA Inc.}
 \begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
sdfrtwrtgsfgbgnghnfghn
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
P net \sep sys doc \sep model of  systems \sep analytics \sep simulation \sep verification 
\end{keyword}
  \end{frontmatter}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Process flowcharts have been in use by industrial engineers since 1921 publication of  ...
\end{document}
```

The pdf shows the author names on both abstract page and the first page.

Comment: Can you provide a document that replicates your current behaviour? We call this a minimal example. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Putting \newpage between \maketitle and the first \section works.  (Note: \maketitle should appear after \end{abstract}.)

Comment: I tried inserting \newpage after \maketitle in the above example, but it did not work.

Comment: It seems that the frontmatter environment and \maketitle are redundant.  (Use one or the other, but not both.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the two samples available under the [`elsarticle` CTAN sources](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle):

- [`elsarticle_template_harv.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-template-harv.tex)
- [`elsarticle_template_num.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-template-num.tex)

Both these provide the following framework for your document:

```
\documentclass[..]{elsarticle}

% <packages>

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

% <title content> \title{..}, \author{..}, \address{..}, ...

\begin{abstract}
% <abstract>
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
% <keywords>
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

% <article content>

\end{document}
```

During `\end{frontmatter}`, the entire title-related content is set. It starts with `\maketitle`, followed by the abstract and then the keywords. So, there's no need to issue a `\maketitle` as `frontmatter` is responsible for doing so.

[image]

```
\documentclass[times,preprint,10pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{A Framework for Analytics and Simulation}
\author[]{R ~K\fnref{fn1}}
\ead{rk@gcos.com}

\author[]{Jack ~G\corref{cor1}\fnref{fn2}}
\ead{Jack@gcos.com}

\author[]{P ~E\fnref{fn3}}
\ead{pe@gcos.com}

\cortext[cor1]{Principal corresponding author}
\fntext[fn1]{LSU}
\fntext[fn2]{CEAS }
\fntext[fn3]{CA Inc.}

\begin{abstract}
sdfrtwrtgsfgbgnghnfghn
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
P net \sep sys doc \sep model of  systems \sep analytics \sep simulation \sep verification 
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
Process flowcharts have been in use by industrial engineers since~1921 publication of \ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not have the front page that has title, authors/afffiliations, abstract.

For blind refereeing you need such a page followed by the paper with NO author names.

Comment: @JagdishG: So what you're saying is that you - the author - need to provide the journal with a blind review copy of the article. And that this blind review copy has two title pages - one that has all the information, and another that doesn't? Seems strange that this onus rests on the author. And even if it did, that the journal doesn't provide this as an option in their document class. Regardless, let's assume the author has to do everything. Could you provide an example (visual) of what the two would look like?